# Finding path is a mostly empty weighted grid

Tags: algorithm, sorting, path-finding, heuristics

I need to find a path from A to B in a 8-connected grid (up/down left/right and diagonals). The problem is, this grid is mosty (25-60%) empty, but there are certain spots with high weighted values (~20 times the empty tiles' weight) that may have to be passed through. I have looked at things like A* with RSR and JPS, but those seems to be for only unweighted grids. Right now I have rolled an A* implementation, but it is slower than I would like. I don't even need a fully optimal algorithm, just something that is close.

Comment: first of all turning an unweighted grid to a weighted grid is relatively simple and should not be too expensive if the grid is mostly empty (just push 20 nodes in the middle). I'd probably try D* lite it might be good. A* is usually pretty fast you might have a bad implementation

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: D* lite is a (fairly complicated) algorithm which extends A* in order to reuse information when re-searching the same graph after small changes to it have been made.  I don't see how that would apply here at all.

Answer (score 1):

[JPS](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~dharabor/data/papers/harabor-grastien-aaai11.pdf) was formulated and analyzed for uniform grids with obstacles. I think that if you treat any "unusual" tiles as you would treat obstacles, JPS will work (i.e. will let you go fast through uniform regions). JPS' author even speculated as much in the comments to his [JPS blog post](http://harablog.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/jump-point-search/) (and it seems fairly obvious):

> simply treat any neighbour which is of a different terrain type to the
>   current node, as forced. This will allow you to quickly search across
>   a uniform-cost region, stop to expand a node when crossing into a
>   different region, and continue jumping on the other side

However you seem to imply that your grid is not just non-uniform, but also has bonus tiles in addition to penalty tiles. You will need to deal with those as well (e.g. bias all grid weights up to avoid negative weights).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't treat weighted tiles as obstacles, as there are cases where I need to go through them.

Comment: "As obstacles" in the JPS sense, i.e. you generate a jump point. More specifically, "treat any neighbour which is of a different terrain type to the current node, as forced", as Harabor himself says in comment #9 to his blog post I linked above. I reworded the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If speed is a concern, consider using graphics hardware (e.g. CUDA or OpenCL).  [This paper](https://www.google.com/url?url=http://scholar.google.com/scholar_url?hl=en&q=http://ecommons.library.cornell.edu/bitstream/1813/6962/2/90-1122.ps&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm37aLjFRQXWcE3l-R-Xsd34PAXvNA&oi=scholarr&rct=j&sa=X&ei=MizzUKu5LaTb0wH1m4CgAQ&ved=0CC0QgAMoADAA&q=robot%20path%20planning%20graphics%20hardware%20siggraph&usg=AFQjCNGuyOvoZJRiXuzhPKGxtoX1_WoMkQ) discusses a "brushfire" algorithm on a 3d grid to find a path for a 2d robot with rotation.  It's almost exactly the same as your problem, although you're in 2d.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot, this is computation on a limited device. I would even consider non-optimal pathfinding solutions, if they are quicker. As long as it gets from A to B decently.

Comment: You should look at the brushfire algorithm anyway.  It labels the who grid with the shortest distance to the goal.  After this you can find a path from _any_ start point A to the goal B in constant time.  If point B stays in the same place in your space while A moves around (as in robot motion problems), this is a good situation.  I have implemented this on regular processors with a priority queue, and it's still blazingly fast.